# Game Rotation vector in Android

Tags: android, android-sensors, cts

How to know if Game Rotation Vector on your phone is of acceptable quality or not supported at all?

I am trying to find out which phone is better for a game that involves lot of rotation. Does the CTS or VTS generate a score based on implementation of game rotation vector?

https://source.android.com/compatibility/vts/ui

Answer (score -1):

CTS verifier has Rotation vector and sensor test cases to validate Rotation vectors in device.
https://source.android.com/compatibility/cts/rotation-vector